# Can I stop another user kicking me out of a RDC?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

When I'm using a Remote Desktop Connection, if another user tries to connect, it simply kicks me out with no warning. I have to then contact the other person saying "Hey, I was using that."

Is there a way I can block another person trying to connect, so that I can continue my work uninterrupted, or at least with a notice telling me someone is trying to connect?

Comment: https://support.managed.com/kb/a1816/how-to-enable-disable-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-2012.aspx on the first page on the google search page

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, thanks. I searched SuperUser far any relevant questions, but I didn't look at google.

Comment: @Ramhound so to clarify, if I open up multiple RDC connections, this will allow us to work simultaneously? What if there is only one Login to the server?

Comment: It's not possible for multiple people to use the same account, I figured, that was sort of obvious.

Comment: Yes. That's a bit of a dumb question.